# Jenkins: Automate Notifications for a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline which performs different steps during deployment. While the deployment is being performed, I would like Jenkins to send notifications about the status of each step to a channel added on communication tool "Teams".

Can someone provide a suggestion on the best route to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Office 365 Connector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Office-365-Connector/) for this.

```
stage('Upload') {
    steps {
        // some instructions here
        office365ConnectorSend webhookUrl: 'https://outlook.office.com/webhook/123456...',
            message: 'Application has been [deployed](https://uat.green.biz)',
            status: 'Success'
    }
}
```

Comment: I did but that does not solve the issue. I need a status on each step involved in the pipeline release. Not just when the build started, ended or pause. It is about each step if that makes sense

Comment: @RajParpani you should be able to execute the Pipeline step anywhere you wish to send notifications.

Comment: Can you please provide an example. The connector you mentioned is only sending notifications on the build. We have to send notifications about each step as it happens in the pipeline to a teams channel